# White vertical line on left side of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a website, and when adding a background image to my CSS there appears to be a random white vertical line on the left side of the screen. I've checked this in both Chrome and Safari browsers. Would anyone be able to help fix this and also explain how it originated?

```css
    .container-fluid {
      background-color: white;
      background-image: none;
      border-color: white;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    }
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .fb {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      float: right;
    }
    a.btn-quote {
      float: right;
      padding-top: auto;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }
    .header {
      background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/green_grass_04_hd_picture_166122.jpg);
      background-repeat: none;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .logo_img {
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      display: block;
    }
    blockquote.slogan {
      font-size: 35px;
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .quote {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
    span.free {
     color: red;
    }
    .premium {
      font-family: 'Graduate';
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .addy {
      max-width: 50%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .fqbutton {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .article {
     margin-right: 250px;
     margin-left: 250px;
    }
    blockquote.construction {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .constructpic {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    footer {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>CCF Lawn Care</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
    </head>
    <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <body>
          <!--   CCF LOGO IMG -->
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hfitzger/image/upload/c_scale,h_650,w_900/v1497668893/CCF_Logo_jsa1ha.jpg" alt="CCF Logo" class="logo_img" />
    <!--     NAV BAR -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CCF Lawn Care</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- FACEBOOK -->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CFFLAWNCARE/" target="blank"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/512/social_facebook_box_blue.png" class="fb"></a>
        <!-- FREE QUOTE BUTTON -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-quote" role="button">Free Quote</a>
    
      </div>
    </nav>
    <blockquote class="slogan"><em>"We work hard so <strong>               <ins>YOU</ins></strong> don't have to!"</em>
          </blockquote>
    
          <!-- HEADER -->
          <div class="header">
          <p class="premium">Premium Lawn Care service in Middle Tennessee</p>
          <!--   FREE QUOTE SECTION -->
          <div class="addy">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here" required>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Free Quote </button>
          </div>
          
        <h3 class="quote">Call 615-870-9822 for a <span class="free">FREE QUOTE</span></h3>
          <!--   ARTICLE SECTION -->
          
    
    
            <blockquote class ="construction">Please come back and view our updates as we are temporarily under construction! <img src="https://server211.web-hosting.com:2083/cpsess0930665082/viewer/home%2fhfitzger%2fpublic_html%2fimages/construction.png" class="constructpic"></blockquote>
          
          <!--   FOOTER -->
          <footer>
            Created and managed by <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hfitzger/image/upload/t_media_lib_thumb/v1497793352/Fitz_Bitz_Logo_jqhmjq.png" alt="Fitz&Bitz Logo" />
          </footer>
          <!-- jQuery CDN -->
             <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
             <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
             <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
        
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Try `.blockquote {
    border-left: none;
}`

Comment: @ihazkose Sorry but that did not seem to work.

Comment: @Ihazkode either `blockquote` or `blockquote.construction` or `.construction`

Comment: @MichaelCoker You are correct. Being more specific in this case - like you mentioned - is much better than my approach. My approach would pretty much break the styling for all block quotes.

Comment: @Ihazkode well you're targeting `.blockquote` which doesn't exist in OP's code :) They have `blockquote.slogan` and `blockquote.construction`

Comment: @MichaelCoker Ha! Silly me! I don't know where I got that from hen. Will try to pay more attention next time. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The white line is because of the blockquote element, you can disable the white border by adding

```
    blockquote {
    border-left: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, it's the default border on `blockquote` from bootstrap. Just set `border-left: none` on an element you want to disable that. In this case, `blockquote.construction`

```css
    .container-fluid {
      background-color: white;
      background-image: none;
      border-color: white;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    }
    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .fb {
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      float: right;
    }
    a.btn-quote {
      float: right;
      padding-top: auto;
      padding-bottom: auto;
    }
    .header {
      background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/green_grass_04_hd_picture_166122.jpg);
      background-repeat: none;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .logo_img {
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      display: block;
    }
    blockquote.slogan {
      font-size: 35px;
      color: red;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .quote {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
    span.free {
     color: red;
    }
    .premium {
      font-family: 'Graduate';
      font-size: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    .addy {
      max-width: 50%;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .fqbutton {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    .article {
     margin-right: 250px;
     margin-left: 250px;
    }
    blockquote.construction {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      border-left: none;
    }
    .constructpic {
      height: 250px;
      width: 250px;
      display: block;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    footer {
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>CCF Lawn Care</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
    </head>
    <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <body>
          <!--   CCF LOGO IMG -->
        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hfitzger/image/upload/c_scale,h_650,w_900/v1497668893/CCF_Logo_jsa1ha.jpg" alt="CCF Logo" class="logo_img" />
    <!--     NAV BAR -->
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CCF Lawn Care</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- FACEBOOK -->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/CFFLAWNCARE/" target="blank"><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/512/social_facebook_box_blue.png" class="fb"></a>
        <!-- FREE QUOTE BUTTON -->
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-quote" role="button">Free Quote</a>
    
      </div>
    </nav>
    <blockquote class="slogan"><em>"We work hard so <strong>               <ins>YOU</ins></strong> don't have to!"</em>
          </blockquote>
    
          <!-- HEADER -->
          <div class="header">
          <p class="premium">Premium Lawn Care service in Middle Tennessee</p>
          <!--   FREE QUOTE SECTION -->
          <div class="addy">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address here" required>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get Free Quote </button>
          </div>
          
        <h3 class="quote">Call 615-870-9822 for a <span class="free">FREE QUOTE</span></h3>
          <!--   ARTICLE SECTION -->
          
    
    
            <blockquote class ="construction">Please come back and view our updates as we are temporarily under construction! <img src="https://server211.web-hosting.com:2083/cpsess0930665082/viewer/home%2fhfitzger%2fpublic_html%2fimages/construction.png" class="constructpic"></blockquote>
          
          <!--   FOOTER -->
          <footer>
            Created and managed by <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/hfitzger/image/upload/t_media_lib_thumb/v1497793352/Fitz_Bitz_Logo_jqhmjq.png" alt="Fitz&Bitz Logo" />
          </footer>
          <!-- jQuery CDN -->
             <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
             <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
             <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
        
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that seemed to fix it. Do you happen to know why it showed up in the first place? Want to try to avoid that mistake next time.

Comment: @HunterFitzgerald you're welcome. *"it's the default border on blockquote from bootstrap"* - you're using bootstrap, and bootstrap applies a left border to all `blockquote` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the unwanted border from Blockquote tag.

In your Css for of Blockquote class replace with below:

```
blockquote.construction {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      border-left: none;
    }
```

**Note :** Also I observed the white border is present in the slogan blockquote as well. The reason it is not visible as the background color there is white. But if you will inspect the element, you will see it there.

I will recommend to add a common class to all blockquote with

> border-left: none;